# how to chnge html header innertext according to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

if the value comes 9 or greater than 9 it should show good , if value between 6 - 9 bad and below 6 poor . how to change the header inner text dynamically according to the variable value- "turbidity". sample data - 9.00

```
<script>
        FusionCharts.ready(function () {
            LoadChart();
        });

        function LoadChart() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://url', // local address
                type: 'GET',
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('xhr success')
                    //if (data.success) {
                    console.log("success");
                    var turbidity = data;
                    if (turbidity >= 9.0) {
                        $('#headerValue').text("Good");
                    }
                    if (turbidity < 9.0 && turbidity > 6.0) {
                        $('#headerValue').text("Normal");
                    }
                    if (turbidity < 6.0) {
                        $('#headerValue').text("Poor");
                    }
                    var phfusioncharts = new FusionCharts({
                        type: 'angulargauge',
                        renderAt: 'ph-container',
                        width: '450',
                        height: '300',
                        dataFormat: 'json',
                        dataSource: {
                            "chart": {
                                "caption": "Turbidity",
                                "lowerLimit": "0",
                                "upperLimit": "12",
                                "showValue": "1",
                                "valueBelowPivot": "1",
                                "theme": "fint"
                            },
                            "colorRange": {
                                "color": [{
                                    "minValue": "0",
                                    "maxValue": "4",
                                    "code": "#6baa01"
                                }, {
                                    "minValue": "4",
                                    "maxValue": "8",
                                    "code": "#f8bd19"
                                }, {
                                    "minValue": "8",
                                    "maxValue": "12",
                                    "code": "#e44a00"
                                }]
                            },
                            "dials": {
                                "dial": [{
                                    "value": turbidity
                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    phfusioncharts.render();
                    //}
                }
            });
        }
</script>

   <td><h3 align="center">Water Quality  : Good</h3> </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the html as this by giving id to status

```
  <td><h3 align="center">Water Quality  : <span id="status">Good</span></h3> </td>
```

Now when you'll get the result just use js to change the text

```
//Suppose you got data in var named data
if(data >=9 )
{
  document.getElementById("status").innerText="Good"
}
else if(data >=6 && data <9 )
{
   document.getElementById("status").innerText="Bad"
}

else 
{
 document.getElementById("status").innerText="Poor"
}
```

Comment: I will suggest you console log the data that you are receiving and check if it is a single value or an object. if it is a signle value then use the same example as given but if it is an obj then use with `.` operator just like `data.propertyname`